# Descending central series of free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

What is the general term $\Gamma_k(F_n)/\Gamma_{k+1}(F_n)$, where $F_n$ is the free group of $n$ generators and $\Gamma_k(F_n)$ is the $k$th term in the descending central series of $F_n$?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for, other than repeating the definition of $\Gamma_k(G)/\Gamma_{k+1}(G)$?

Comment: But for the rather boring $\;\Gamma_1/\Gamma_2\cong \Bbb Z^n\;$, it may be there is not cute, nice form for each subsequent factor of the lower central series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are free abelian groups with free basis consisting of the images of certain *basic commutators*. Check the wikipedia article on central series for references. (It is all in Marshall Hall's book on Group Theory.)

Comment: Theorem 10.2.3 of Hall's book says that if $G$ is generated by $x_1,\cdots,x_r$, then $\Gamma_k(G)/\Gamma_{k+1}(G)$ is generated by the simple commutators $(y_1,\cdots,y_k)\mod \Gamma_{k+1}(G)$, where $y$'s are chosen from $x_1,\cdots,x_r$ and are not necessarily distinct. So: 1. Why it is a free Abelian group if $G$ is a free group? 2. What is the rank of $\Gamma_k(F_r)/\Gamma_{k+1}(F_r)$?

Comment: I just read from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra that Witt showed that the number of basic commutators of degree k in the free Lie algebra on an $m$-element set is given by the necklace polynomial: $$N_k=\displaystyle\frac{1}{k}\displaystyle\sum_{d|k}\mu(d)\cdot m^{\frac{k}{d}};$$